# how to find all registry symbolic links?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

There is a method to see if a registry key is a symbolic link?

Comment: Symbolic link to what? The registry is just a list of settings and configuration information. How would it have a symbolic link to something else?

Comment: Well...isn't this interesting...another way for the registry to get more complicated. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/regsymlink.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sepago.de/e/helge/2008/05/04/free-tool-list-registry-links-reglink